# nstimer not working in background even after enabling Voip in info.plist in xcode 5

Tags: ios, background, voip

I am developing a voip app. But in my app even after enabling voip in `info.plist`, when app goes to background, all functions and timers stop.

Comment: Show us the `info.plist`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <string>voip</string>
 <string>audio</string>
</array>
</plist>  This is how my plist is configured for voip apps

Comment: That's not a valid Info.plist.

Comment: I am unable to add screenshot of plist here. When I copy pasted, its displaying as above.

Answer (score 0):

Your `info.plist` should contain the following to enable VoIP background modes -

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

But it is simpler to just tick the right box on the Capabilities tab

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already set this . But still not working.